# User Input to Alphabet Pyramid Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, logic

I have tried to print user input value into pyramid pattern,but i've got an error and it cannot placed my span tag as a pyramid pattern format

```js
function getPyramid(num1){
   var count=$('#'+num1).val().length;
   var string ="";
  for (var i=1;i<=count;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=count-i;j++){
      string +=" "
    }
    for(var k=1;k <=2*i-1;k++){
      string += num1[k]+" ";
    }
     string +="<br/>";
  }
    $('#pyramid').text(string);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input type="text" id="textBoxValue" />
<button  value="Submit"   onclick="getPyramid('textBoxValue');" >Submit</button>
<h2>
      <pre  id="pyramid"></pre>
</h2>
</html>
```

Acutually i want ,If user input is demo

```
   d
  d e
 d e m
d e m o
```

Where i am doing wrong..?

Comment: First you have an extra `"` in `id="textBoxValue"" `. Second what is the desired result?

Comment: Pyramid is a Python-based web framework provided by the Pylons Project. Do not use the "pyramid" tag for displaying items in a pyramid shape.

Comment: Yes i misplaced empty spaces in my texboxvalue,i've correct my post

Comment: @RNK also when you do `num1[k]` num1 refers to your selector and not the value of the selector

Comment: thanks for your valuable time @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 2):

too many errors
1- use `string +=  '\n'  // not "<br/>";`
2- num1 value is `textBoxValue`, not `demo`
3- the position of the first character in a string is zero, not one
4-...

javascript solution
(the tag is present in the question)

```js
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let characters = myForm.textBoxValue.value.trim() 
    , output     = ''
    ;
  for (let count=1, spacing=characters.length; count < characters.length; count++)
    {
    output += ' '.repeat(--spacing)
           + [...characters.substr(0,count)].join(' ') 
           + '\n'
    }
  output += [...characters].join(' ')
  pyramid.textContent = output
  }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="textBoxValue" value="demo">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>
  <pre id="pyramid"></pre>
</h2>
```

> your jQuery corrected...

```js
function getPyramid(num1)
  {
  let
    inputText = $('#'+num1).val()
  , count     = inputText.length
  , string    = ''
    ;
  for (let i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
    for(let j=1;j<=count-i;j++)
      {
      string +=" "
      }
    for(let k=0;k<i;k++)
      {
      string += inputText[k]+" ";
      }
    string +=  '\n'  // not "<br/>";
    }
  $('#pyramid').text(string);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textBoxValue" value="demo">
<button onclick="getPyramid('textBoxValue');">Submit</button>
<h2>
  <pre id="pyramid"></pre>
</h2>
```

Comment: yes..!it's useful to me ,I've identify my mistakes to get learn new thinks.Thanks man..!

Answer (score 1):

replace your `id="textBoxValue""` to `id="textBoxValue"`
replace your `$('#pyramid').text(string)` to

```
$('#pyramid').html(string)
```

in your string there is `undefined` also.
and `num1` is id selector so in your `count` there is length of your input.
so basically you have to remove length `$('#'+num1).val()`.

here is working example.
what you done wrong is:

1. you just start with `1` for i,j and k which need to be `0`
2. and `2 * i - 1` provide `undefined`

```js
function getPyramid(num1) {
  var value = $('#' + num1).val();
  var string = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <= value.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= value.length - i; j++) {
      string += " "
    }
    for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) {
      string += value[k] + " ";
    }
    string += "<br/>";
  }
  $('#pyramid').html(string);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #editable {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="textBoxValue" />
  <button value="Submit" onclick="getPyramid('textBoxValue');">Submit</button>
  <h2>
    <pre id="pyramid"></pre>
  </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would still not work, since op is actually not taking the value of the input but the parsed selector

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen updated answer.

Comment: yaha its working..! Thanks for your valuable time @MohitSharma

Comment: **<pre/>** tag  gives exact same postion of values